# Rotating 2D Vector by unknown angle such that its direction vector is [1,0]

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I am trying to rotate a vector `[x,y]` around the origin such that when the rotation is completed it lies on the X axis. In order to do this, I'm first computing the angle between `[x,y]` and `[1,0]`, then applying a simple 2D [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to it. I'm using [numericjs](http://www.numericjs.com/index.php) to work with the vectors.

```
math.angleBetween = function(A, B) {                                                                                               
    var x = numeric.dot(A, B) / (numeric.norm2(A) * numeric.norm2(B));                                                             
    if(Math.abs(x) <= 1) {                                                                                                         
        return Math.acos(x);                                                                                                       
    } else {                                                                                                                       
        throw "Bad input to angleBetween";                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                              
};

math.alignToX = function(V) {
    var theta = -math.angleBetween([1,0], V);
    var R = [[Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta)],
             [Math.sin(theta), Math.cos(theta)]];
    return numeric.dot(R, V);
};
```

(Note: `math` is a namespace object within my project. `Math` is ye olde math object.)

This code works *sometimes*, however there are occasions where no matter how many times I run `math.alignToX` the vector never even gets close to aligning with the X axis. I'm testing this by checking if the `y` coordinate is less than `1e-10`.

I've also tried using `Math.atan2` with an implicit `z` coordinate of 0, but the results have been the same. Errors are not being thrown. Some example results:

```
math.alignToX([152.44444444444434, -55.1111111111111]) 
// result: [124.62691466033475, -103.65652585400568]
// expected: [?, 0]

math.alignToX([372, 40])
// result: [374.14435716712336, -2.0605739337042905e-13]
// expected: [?, 0]
// this value has abs(y coordinate) < 1e-10, so its considered aligned
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're rotating something other than your vector, then you'll need to use your `R` matrix.  But if you just need to rotate your vector, the result will be `[Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y),0]`.

Comment: This is much better than my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, he'd need R to rotate other points similarly, but there's no need to compute trig functions to compute R.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the task of building a rotation matrix that aligns a known 2d vector with [1, 0] doesn't require any trigonometric functions at all.

In fact, if [x y] is your vector and s is its length (s = Sqrt(x*x + y*y)), then the transformation that maps [x y] to align with [1 0] (pure rotation, no scaling) is just:

```
          [ x y]
T = 1/s^2 [-y x]
```

For example, suppose your vector is [Sqrt(3)/2, 1/2].  This is a unit vector as you can easily check so s = 1.

```
    [Sqrt(3)/2     1/2   ]
T = [  -1/2     Sqrt(3)/2]
```

Multiplying T by our vector we get:

```
    [Sqrt(3)/2     1/2   ][Sqrt(3)/2]   [1]
T = [  -1/2     Sqrt(3)/2][  1/2    ] = [0]
```

So in finding the rotation angle (which in this case is Pi/6) and then creating the rotation matrix, you've just come full circle back to what you started with.  The rotation angle for [Sqrt(3)/2, 1/2] is Pi/2, and cos(Pi/2) is Sqrt(3)/2 = x, sin(pi/2) is 1/2 = y.

Put another way, if you know the vector, you ALREADY know the sine and cosine of it's angle with the x axis from the definition of sine and cosine:

```
cos a = x/s
sin a = y/s where s = || [x, y] ||, is the length of the vector.
```

Comment: Very nice.  You may want to add that `s=Sqrt(x*x+y*y)`, so that `T=1/(x*x+y*y) * [[x y][-y x]]`.

Comment: Having thought about it, I realized: if you map `[x,y]` to `[1,0]`, then you have scaled things.  So we should have `T=1/s*[[x y][-y x]]`.

Comment: @Teepeemm, that's how I had it in my first draft, then I reread the OP's problem and saw that he wanted the same direction, not magnitude.  At least that's how I interpreted it.  Do you agree?

Comment: I read OP as wanting the vector with the direction of `[1,0]` and the magnitude of `[x,y]`.  For example, I think the second example he gives is what he wanted.  (Another way of looking at it: since `T` is only acting on `[x,y]` and not any other point, asking "How can I make it `[1,0]`?" would be a ridiculous question.)  But I will admit that if `T` were supposed to be acting on other points, then looking to make `[x,y]` into `[1,0]` would be a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is so mind-bendingly obvious that I cannot believe I didn't see it. While I'm checking the *domain* of `Math.acos`, I'm not checking the *range* at all! The problem occurs when the vector lies outside of the range (which is `[0,PI]`). Here is what I did to fix it:

```
math.alignToX = function(V) {
    var theta = -math.angleBetween([1,0], V);
    var R = [[Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta)],
             [Math.sin(theta), Math.cos(theta)]];
    var result = numeric.dot(R, V);
    if(Math.abs(result[1]) < ZERO_THRESHOLD) {
        return result;
    } else {
        V = numeric.dot([[-1, 0], [0, -1]], V); // rotate by PI
        theta = -math.angleBetween([1,0], V);
        R = [[Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta)],
             [Math.sin(theta), Math.cos(theta)]];
        result = numeric.dot(R, V);
        if(Math.abs(result[1]) < ZERO_THRESHOLD) {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw "Unable to align " + V; // still don't trust it 100%
        }
    }
};
```

For the broken example I gave above, this produces:

```
[162.10041088743887, 2.842170943040401e-14]
```

The Y coordinate on this result is significantly less than my ZERO_THRESHOLD (1e-10). I almost feel bad that I solved it myself, but I don't think I would have done so nearly as quickly had I not posted here. I saw the problem when I was checking over my post for typos.